# indexing on datetime object within a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array containing date (as datetime object), prices and a category as an integer:

```
array([[datetime.date(2013, 6, 5), 11.42, 1],
   [datetime.date(2013, 6, 7), 63.97, 1],
   [datetime.date(2013, 6, 19), 3.92, 1],
   [datetime.date(2013, 6, 19), 16.25, 2],
   [datetime.date(2013, 6, 20), 11.0, 2],
   [datetime.date(2013, 6, 22), 32.72, 2],
   [datetime.date(2013, 6, 25), 16.6, 3],
   [datetime.date(2013, 6, 26), 2.95, 2],
   [datetime.date(2013, 7, 1), 6.27, 1],
   [datetime.date(2013, 7, 1), 2.95, 1]], dtype=object)
```

Suming up the prices if a category is met via `index_cat=(array==2).any(axis=1)`, followed by by `np.sum(array[index_cat][:,1])` is obvious.

What I want to achieve now is basically the same, but instead of selecting a category, I want to take the datetime object's month or month-year combination as a criterion.

So I thought a `index_june=(array==datetime.dateime(month='06').any(axis=1)` should do it, but, even with lots of searching, I could not find a way to do this.

So, how do I express this to match the datetime object considering the absence of wildcards?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's vectorize function:

```
getmonth = np.vectorize(lambda d: getattr(d, "month"))
ind = getmonth(arr[:,0]) == 11
```

another way is list comprehension:

```
ind = np.array([a[0].month == 11 for a in arr])
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the quick and clear answer! I prefer the list comprehension way as it suits my python-knowledge better (for now)..

Comment: It also seems to be slightly faster.